# how to call callNamedPipe through c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two exe. 1st one is in c# and other is in c++.How to pass message through callNamedPipe in c# exe to another exe.pls me some guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you'll need to be use classes from System.IO.Pipes. Specifically NamedPipeServerStream and NamedPipeClientStream.
MSDN has sample code here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx

For the C/C++ side you can find sample code here:

Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365588%28VS.85%29.aspx

Client: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365592%28VS.85%29.aspx